# SSIS Import File csv ="" text delimiter ignore =

Tags: import, ssis, ssis-2008

I'm importing a csv file and for some reason the text delimiter is not just a double quote it's an = sign and the double quotes.  is there a way in ssis to open the file, replace the = sign in the entire file and then import it into a table?

Comment: please give a sample row, I'm not sure if it is used as a text qualifier or a column delimiter

Comment: Here's a sample of the data
`="011",="60",="011-60",="12971 X1"`
the double quotes mean string but I have no idea why the equals signs are in there.  As a matter of fact it would be a great first step in ssis to replace all equals signs in the file before the import but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Is this a one off import?  If so just do a find and replace all outside ssis. Your otjer option would be to put the data into a staging table, then from staging table perform an update to the records.to rove the quotes and equal sign. Alternatively, create a view which reads off the staging table which removes the unwanted characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had almost similar situation and you could do what I did:

First dataflow task:

1. Flat File Source with Format=Delimited, Text qualifier=< none >, in Advanced tab ColumnDelimiter={LF} and OutputColumnWidt=8000. The idea is in opening file as 1-column csv to replace wrong characters in each row.
   [image]
2. Derived column with Expression=REPLACE(Column0,"=","")
   [image]
3. Flat File Destination with same parameters as in the source.

Second dataflow task runs after first.

4. We use saved file as Flat File Source but this time we have to split its columns using delimiter=Comma and Text qualifier=Quote

Comment: That did it!  I was playing around in there but couldn't get the right settings, thank you for the direction!!